# Select returns no value even it already have a default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a select item and I already added a default value for it, but after submitting the form, it returns an empty string. Why is this?

My code:

```
var c = $('#c').val();

populateSelect(cs, '#c', 'My select option');

function populateSelect(json, element, defaulttext) {

  $(element).find('option').remove().end().attr('disabled', false).append($('<option selected>').text(defaulttext).attr('value', ''));
  $.each(json, function(i, value) {
    $(element).append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
  });

  if (defaulttext != undefined) {
    $(element).val(defaulttext);
  }

}
```

Comment: because it has no value? `.attr('value', '')`

Comment: I already added this value 'My select option' when I called the populate function

Comment: Yes you set the value of the default one to an empty string.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you set the [**`selected` attribute**](http://html.com/attributes/option-selected/) in your jQuery, you're not actually setting a [**`value`**](http://html.com/attributes/option-value/) for that selection. You need to change `.attr('value', '')` to something like `.attr('value', 'default')`. To pass it through from your function parameter, you're looking for `.attr('value', defaulttext)`.

In addition to this, you'll also need to ensure that your `select` field has a [**`name` attribute**](http://html.com/attributes/input-name/), in order for the value to be picked up once the form is submitted.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: do you mean changing $(element).val(defaulttext); ?

Comment: If you want to pass it through your function, you're looking for `.attr('value', defaulttext)`.